# Reguex to find numbers with comma, points, percentage and USD

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a code in python and I need to find different kinds of numbers such as

- 4%
- 4.5%
- .00%
- 1,543,000.45
- 1000
- 105.45
- US$1,435.45
- US 2,435.45
- USD 4000

I am using regex to complete this task. Right now I am able to identify numbers without percentage with this expression:
'(:?^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:0-9))?(?:.\d*[0-9])?)?(?!\S)'
and with percentage with this expression:
(:?^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:0-9))?(?:.\d*[0-9])?%)?(?!\S)'

But I am having problems to identify with numbers like:

- US$1,435.45
- US 2,435.45
- USD 4000

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The question you asked here is too broad and also is almost identical to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484475/regex-to-find-numbers-with-commas-points-and-percentage-signs-in-a-string-in-py) which was closed yesterday.

Comment: see if this works for you `items = ["4%","4.5%",'.00%',"1,543,000.45",'1000',".55%",'105.45','US$1,435.45','US 1,435.45','US1,435.45','USD 1,435.45']
for item in items:
    print(re.findall(r'([USD\s\d,$.%]+)',item))`